# Sympy solve of cubic equation appears to be wrong and includes imaginary units. What is wrong?

Tags: python, sympy

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import x

f = x**3 - 3*x + 1
res = solve(f)
print(res)
```

However, it gives an incorrect answer with imaginary units. Checking via `subs` doesn't return 0, either.

UPD:

res:

```
[-3/((-1/2 - sqrt(3)*I/2)*(27/2 + 27*sqrt(3)*I/2)**(1/3)) - (-1/2 - sqrt(3)*I/2)*(27/2 + 27*sqrt(3)*I/2)**(1/3)/3,
 -(-1/2 + sqrt(3)*I/2)*(27/2 + 27*sqrt(3)*I/2)**(1/3)/3 - 3/((-1/2 + sqrt(3)*I/2)*(27/2 + 27*sqrt(3)*I/2)**(1/3)),
 -(27/2 + 27*sqrt(3)*I/2)**(1/3)/3 - 3/(27/2 + 27*sqrt(3)*I/2)**(1/3)]
```

subs check:

```
>>> print(f.subs(x, res[0]))
1 + (-1/2 - sqrt(3)*I/2)*(27/2 + 27*sqrt(3)*I/2)**(1/3) + (-3/((-1/2 - sqrt(3)*I/2)*(27/2 + 27*sqrt(3)*I/2)**(1/3)) - (-1/2 - sqrt(3)*I/2)*(27/2 + 27*sqrt(3)*I/2)**(1/3)/3)**3 + 9/((-1/2 - sqrt(3)*I/2)*(27/2 + 27*sqrt(3)*I/2)**(1/3))
```

The plot:

```
>>> plot(f, xlim=(-2, 2), ylim=(-2, 2))
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Show the result of that print, don't just tell us about it.  Show the subs as well.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha's solution also includes imaginary values in all three roots - even though the roots themselves are real.  That appears to just be the simplest exact representation of the roots.

Comment: Substitute x = 2 cos(theta) and solve it by trigonometry. The roots are 2.cos(2.pi/9), 2.cos(8.pi/9) and 2.cos(14.pi/9)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's try to convert the symbolic solution computed by sympy to floating point numbers:

```py
from sympy import *
var("x")
f = x**3 - 3*x + 1
sol = solve(f)
print([s.n() for s in sol])
# [0.347296355333861 - 0.e-23*I, 1.53208888623796 + 0.e-20*I, -1.87938524157182 + 0.e-23*I]
```

Here you can see very small imaginary parts. These are rounding errors. We can remove them with this:

```py
print([s.n(chop=True) for s in sol])
# [0.347296355333861, 1.53208888623796, -1.87938524157182]
```

Now, I'm going to substitute the first symbolic solution back into the equation:

```py
print(f.subs(x, sol[0]))
# 1 + (-1/2 - sqrt(3)*I/2)*(27/2 + 27*sqrt(3)*I/2)**(1/3) + (-3/((-1/2 - sqrt(3)*I/2)*(27/2 + 27*sqrt(3)*I/2)**(1/3)) - (-1/2 - sqrt(3)*I/2)*(27/2 + 27*sqrt(3)*I/2)**(1/3)/3)**3 + 9/((-1/2 - sqrt(3)*I/2)*(27/2 + 27*sqrt(3)*I/2)**(1/3))
```

It doesn't appear to be zero, but we can ask sympy to simplify it, like this:

```py
print(f.subs(x, sol[0]).simplify())
# 0
```

As you can see, the symbolic solutions computed by sympy are correct.

Answer (score 5):

The other answer is good and shows that the expressions given by SymPy are correct even if they involve complex numbers. I just want to clarify a bit why `solve` returns this result.

The reason that these expressions are given is because it is not possible to express the roots of the given polynomial in radicals without the use of complex numbers due to casus irreducibilis:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis

SymPy provides two simple ways to avoid casus irreducibilis when seeking an exact representation of the roots of an irreducible cubic. One is to ask for expressions that involve trig functions rather than pure radical expressions:

```
In [2]: roots(x**3 - 3*x + 1, x, trig=True)
Out[2]: 
⎧      ⎛π⎞          ⎛2⋅π⎞          ⎛4⋅π⎞   ⎫
⎨-2⋅cos⎜─⎟: 1, 2⋅cos⎜───⎟: 1, 2⋅cos⎜───⎟: 1⎬
⎩      ⎝9⎠          ⎝ 9 ⎠          ⎝ 9 ⎠   ⎭
```

Here the trigonometric expressions like `-2*cos(pi/9)` are purely real and can represent the solutions exactly without the use of intermediate complex numbers in the expressions. It is not always possible to express the roots of any polynomial like this (depending on e.g. the degree of the polynomial) just like it is not always possible to represent the roots in radicals (see the Abel-Ruffini theorem).

A more general way to represent the roots of an irreducible polynomial is using RootOf:

```
In [3]: real_roots(x**3 - 3*x + 1)
Out[3]: 
⎡       ⎛ 3             ⎞         ⎛ 3             ⎞         ⎛ 3             ⎞⎤
⎣CRootOf⎝x  - 3⋅x + 1, 0⎠, CRootOf⎝x  - 3⋅x + 1, 1⎠, CRootOf⎝x  - 3⋅x + 1, 2⎠⎦

In [4]: [r.n() for r in real_roots(x**3 - 3*x + 1)]
Out[4]: [-1.87938524157182, 0.347296355333861, 1.53208888623796]
```

Some people dislike RootOf because it is somehow not "explicit" but it is the best way to represent polynomial roots symbolically. The RootOf representation combines the algebraic knowledge that the number is an exact root of a given polynomial with the precise determination that the root is real or not and the numeric capability to compute the roots to any desired precision:

```
In [5]: for r in real_roots(x**3-3*x+1):
   ...:     print(r, "=", r.evalf(50))
   ...: 
CRootOf(x**3 - 3*x + 1, 0) = -1.8793852415718167681082185546494629398724162685289
CRootOf(x**3 - 3*x + 1, 1) = 0.34729635533386069770343325353862959200075135436814
CRootOf(x**3 - 3*x + 1, 2) = 1.5320888862379560704047853011108333478716649141608
```

With RootOf we always know if any root is real or not and so there are no small imaginary parts when the RootOf is evaluated numerically. For non-real roots we know exactly which roots are conjugates of one another etc. Every element of the algebraically closed field of algebraic numbers can be represented in the RootOf representation meaning all roots of any polynomial with rational coefficients of any degree. With RootOf we can avoid the limitations of casus irreducibilis, the Abel-Ruffini theorem and the messiness of Cardano's formulae all at the same time.

It would be better if SymPy's `solve` function returned RootOf here rather than non-real radical expressions but it would probably be more confusing for many SymPy users than casus irreducibilis is. Currently `solve` will return `RootOf` but only if `roots` fails to find radical expressions for all roots.